# Error when relating two tables with BigInteger datatype in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) automatically maps columns on the background. And after working with Grails a year now, I can assume that varying datatypes makes no difference to [gorm](/questions/tagged/gorm)— it can handle any non-primitive datatypes as its column without any much configuration. But see the given example mapping on Grails 2.4 using Hibernate 4:

```
class TableA {
    String id

    static hasMany = [joinTable: TableAJoinTableB]

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}

class TableB {
    BigInteger id

    static hasMany = [joinTable: TableAJoinTableB]

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}

class TableAJoinTableB {
    String prop1

    static belongsTo = [tablea: TableA, tableb: TableB]

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ["tablea", "tableb"]
    }
}
```

Assuming that the data at hand respects this relationship, you perform a `JOIN` query to the three tables using:

```
// Assuming the query below will *always* retrieve no more than 1 row.
TableAJoinTableB join = TableAJoinTableB.createCriteria().get {
    tablea {
        eq("id", "1KDSURT743")
    }
    eq("prop1", "AT")
}
```

And simply access the values from `TableA`and `TableB` using this:

```
println "id of TableA via join: " + join?.tablea?.id
println "id of TableB via join: " + join?.tableb?.id
```

But I can't get to make the second line work, instead it throws an error:

> **org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException**
>
> Provided `id` of the wrong type for class `TableB`. Expected: class `java.math.BigInteger`, got class `java.lang.String`.

I could always change the `id` of `TableB` to `String` just to end this argument. But there are times when I cannot do that:

> e.g. the database primary key is REALLY a number thus will cause an *"Invalid number"* error when performing a query if I forced its id to String

How can I tell `TableAJoinTableB` to join with `TableB` using `BigInteger`? Isn't Hibernate assume that they should connect using `BigInteger` since its the datatype of the referencing table's `id`. The connection to `TableA` is already working and I can see that the connection to `TableB` is not supposed to be that way different.

Comment: This works with Grails 2.4.4, hibernate 4.3.6.1 and MySql 5.6.27 and MySQL Driver 5.1.29. Do you have a different config?

Comment: @Sandeep I'm connecting to an Oracle Database.

Comment: Enable Hibernate logs `trace 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder','org.hibernate.SQL'` and then check the queries that are being fired when you execute create criteria.

Comment: One solution you can try is by creating overloaded setter methods for id, one that accepts String and another that accepts BigInteger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an overloaded setter methods for `id` can be the answer. But it defeats the purpose of auto-mapping of Hibernate foreign keys. The simple solution that I discovered solved the problem:

```
TableAJoinTableB join = TableAJoinTableB.createCriteria().get {
    tablea {
        eq("id", "1KDSURT743")
    }
    eq("prop1", "AT")
}

println "id of TableA via join: " + join?.tablea?.id

// These won't work and causes the same error to be thrown.
// I'll try to investigate why:
// println "id of TableB via join: " + join?.getTableb()?.id
// println "id of TableB via join: " + join?.getTableb()?.get("id")
// println "id of TableB via join: " + join?.tableb?.id
// println "id of TableB via join: " + join?.tableb?.get("id")

// However, the following line works:
println "id of TableB via join: " + join?.getTableb().getId()
```